# C++0x: when a temporary object equals another temporary object

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, move-semantics

```
struct F
{
private:
    int* data;

public:
    F( int n ) 
    { 
        data = new int; 
        *data = n; 
    }

    F( int* p ) 
    { 
        data = p; 
    }

    F& operator=( const F& f ) 
    { 
        *data = *(f.get_data()); 
        return *this; 
    }

    F& operator=( F&& f ) 
    {
        delete data;
        data = f.data;
        f.data = nullptr;
        return *this;
    }

    F& operator=( int n ) { *data = n; return *this; }

    F operator()() 
    {
        F cpy_f( data );
        return std::move( cpy_f );
    }

    int* get_data() const { return data; }
};

int main()
{
    F f( 12 );
    F g( 14 );
    f() = g();
    cout << *(f.get_data()) << endl;
}
```

In this example, `f()` and `g()` respectively return a temporary object, so `f()=g()` results in an expression of **temporary object equal to temporary object**. I would have expected that the answer is 14 if the value is correctly copied. However, it is **NOT** calling the **copy assignment**, **BUT** calling the **move assignment**! As a result, the answer is not 14.

This makes me really confused. Although the returning objects from `f()` and `g()` are temporary, they are sharing some information with some other objects. It implies the temporary objects might be doing some works shortly for the shared information. So I am supposed that semantically calling copy assignment would be the correct behaviors.

ps. My compiler is g++4.7 20110430

Comment: Add a destructor and you'll start seeing huge problems

Comment: It may be helpful to follow the Rule of 3/5 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782757/rule-of-three-becomes-rule-of-five-with-c11

Answer (score 4):

Your `operator()` returns a value, rather than a reference or pointer. Therefore, it returns a temporary. Temporaries *implicitly* bind to && preferentially (they are the only types to do so). Therefore, if there is a move assignment operator for them to use, they will prefer to use it.

Your problem is that you stopped doing reasonable things when you did this in your `operator()` function:

```
F cpy_f( data );
```

The constructor of `F` that takes a pointer uses the pointer value itself, effectively adopting the pointer. At that moment, you now have *two* `F` instances that point to the same data.

If that's something you want to be reasonable, then you *cannot* have your move assignment operator delete the pointer. You need to reconcile the fact that you can have two `F` instances that point to the same thing. The two need to share ownership of the pointer. So... how do you plan to do that?

I would suggest getting rid of this constructor altogether. It will only create more problems for you. I would also suggest using a `std::unique_ptr<int> data;` instead of a naked pointer. That way, you don't have to write a move constructor/assignment operator (though you do need a copy constructor/assignment operator).

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an instance which has a pointer pointing the same location. The instance created with `F::operator()` does **not** share the pointer itself.

`f()=g()` is equivalent to f().operator=(g()) and `g()` creates a temporary instance, so it is correct to call move assignment.

The problem is that `f` has a dangling pointer after the execution of `f()=g()`. `f()` creates an temporary instance, it deletes the pointer in the move assignment operator, but `f` itself still has a pointer which points the deleted location.

I'm not sure what you're doing with those complicated code but you'd better rewrite the code with `std::shared_ptr` or something.

p.s. You don't need `std::move` in returning an instance. Your compiler has RVO features if you didn't turn these off.